# jqGrid tableToGrid loses scrollbar on sort

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I'm using the tableToGrid method of jqGrid to convert an ASP.Net GridView into a jqGrid.  The grid is converted and everything looks good.  But once I click a column to sort by, the data gets sorted and then I lose the vertical scrollbar, or really, just the ability to scroll.  It seems like it wants to implement paging when I don't have any paging.  For example, the data being returned and bound to the grid contains about 75 rows that I just list; with no paging.  After I click a column to sort, it shows about 20 rows, there is no vertical scroll bar and I can't see the other rows (the ones past 20).  Do I have to setup paging?

Thank you for any assistance.

```
tableToGrid("#ContentPlaceHolder1_grid",
        { height: 600,
          forceFit: true,
          viewrecords: true, 
          hidegrid: true,
          gridview: true,
          autowidth: true,
          colNames: ['Id', 'Number', 'Facility', 'Department', 'Category', 'Job Title', 'Date Last Modified'],
          colModel: [
              { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 30, hidden: true },
              { name: 'Number', index: 'Number', width: 75, title: false },
              { name: 'Facility', index: 'Facility', width: 120 },
              { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 120 },
              { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 120 },
              { name: 'Job_Title', index: 'Job_Title', width: 170, sortable: false },
              { name: 'Date_Last_Modified', index: 'Date_Last_Modified', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'right' }
          ]
        });
```

My GridView is wrapped inside an UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="content" class="ui-widget half-height-widget">
            <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top"> 
                <h2 id="PageTitle">
                    <img alt="JSA" src="Images/jsa.png"/>Open JSA Document
                    <span id="toolbar">
                        <asp:Button ID="open" Text="Open" CssClass="button" runat="server" />
                    </span>                        
                </h2>
            </div>        
            <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"> 
                <div id="content-div" style="overflow: auto;">
                    <div id="files" style="height: 601px;">
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                    <ItemTemplate><img class="jqGrid-icon" onclick='alert(<%# Eval("Id") %>);' alt='' src="images/magnifier-medium.png" /></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Facility" HeaderText="Facility" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Job_Title" HeaderText="Job Title" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Last_Modified" 
                                    HeaderText="Date Last Modified" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML table which you use as input for `tableToGrid`? The code of GridView can't be helpful.

Comment: Hi Oleg.  Do you want to see the code between <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grid" style="border-collapse:collapse;"> ... </table> or the entire HTML of the page?  Thank you!

Comment: Oleg, here is a link to the view source.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6032362/viewsource.html  I hope this helps.  Thank you.  I like the way jqGrid looks using the jQuery UI but the frustration I deal on a daily basis with it...  Ugh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just include `rowNum: 1000` in the list of jqGrid options in the second parameters of `tableToGrid`. If you don't have visible pager the local data paging still exist. So you should increase the page size from the default value [rowNum: 20](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) to any large enough value (like 1000 or 10000 for example). Probably the usahe of `height: 'auto'` is one more option which you need.

See the modified demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DrZ.htm).

Comment: Oleg, thank you so much for taking the time to create that demo for me.  By setting the rowNum: 1000, seemed to do the trick.  I'm printing the code you put together so I have it for reference.  You are awesome!  Thank you!!!